# syntax error can't pinpoint the bug in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I continue to receive a syntax error and can't figure out why, please help.

```
alert ("CAN YOU BEAT VALERIE AT ROCK PAPER SCISSORS?");
var userChoise = prompt ("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
computerChoice = "rock";
}

else if (0.34 >= computerChoice < 0.67) {
computerChoice = "paper";
}

else (0.67 >= computerChoice <= 1) {
computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log("Valerie Dam picks" + " " + computerChoice);
```

Chrome Console throws the following syntax error:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
> at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
> at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
> ```

Comment: It might help if you included the text of your syntax error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `0.34 >= computerChoice < 0.67` is not valid in JavaScript. Use something like `computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.67` instead.
2. the last block of `else` [`else (0.67 >= computerChoice <= 1)`...] should be `else if`.

So your corrected code should be like this:

```
alert ("CAN YOU BEAT VALERIE AT ROCK PAPER SCISSORS?");
var userChoise = prompt ("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}

else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}

else if (computerChoice >= 0.67 && computerChoice <= 1) {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}

console.log("Valerie Dam picks" + " " + computerChoice);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5rpuk64b/)

Comment: But the `computerChoice >= 0.34` and `computerChoice >= 0.67` in the second and third `if` statements are superfluous and should be removed. And why would the last one need to be an `else if`? By definition the result of `Math.random` is less than (not less than or equal to) one.

Answer (score 0):

This structure doesn't exist in javascript

```
0.34 >= computerChoice < 0.67
```

It's not possible to express a range like that. You need to replace it by

```
computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice < 0.67
```

The same applies for

```
0.67 >= computerChoice <= 1
```

Comment: But if `computerChoice` is less than 0.67, it will also always be less than 0.34. You failed to fix the OP's error in defining the comparisons.

Comment: @torazaburo: thanks, I made the mistake of building the condition exactly as user did. Just fixed it